# Are these field extensions equal?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ a zero of the polynomial $x^5+x+1$. I want to prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2)$ but I am out of ideas since the polynomial is not irreducible, but I want to prove this without computing the factors of the polynomial.

Furthermore, what is the degree of the extension $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\alpha \sqrt{2})$? And why is $x^7-6$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha \sqrt{2})$?

I am lost on this exercise, so any hint will be useful.

Comment: You need to show only that $\alpha\in\mathbb Q(\alpha^2)$

Comment: You should prove that $\alpha\sqrt {2}\notin \mathbb{Q} (\alpha) $ and it is sufficient to show that $\sqrt{2}\notin\mathbb {Q} (\alpha) $.

Comment: Assume $\beta\in\mathbb{Q} (\alpha) $ with $\beta^2=2$ and consider that $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q} (\beta) \subseteq \mathbb{Q} (\alpha) $. Can you derive a contradiction using degrees of $\alpha, \beta$ over $\mathbb{Q} $? You should try to post your attempt based on this approach.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint for the first part:** Since $\alpha^5+\alpha+1=0,$ we have $\alpha^6+\alpha^2+\alpha=0.$